# Why does random() not work in windows?

Tags: c++, random

Why does the C++ `random()` command not work on Windows? I made a running program with the `random()` command on Ubuntu. This command generates a random integer. Online there isn't much to find about this command. What confuses me is that the code is not altered in any way, and the same program is used on both operating systems to run the code.

Is there any structural difference in these 2 operating systems that prohibits the command from working on one of them?

simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++){
        r = random();
        cout << r <<endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you  have?

Comment: 1.  define "not work".   2.  did you seed it?

Comment: C++ standard library does not provide a function named `random()`. Show your code.

Comment: `random()` isn't a standard (portable, i..e) function AFAIK. `rand()` is.

Comment: Could it be that you miss srand(time(NULL)) or something at the beginning?

Comment: The **operating system** has nothing to do with what language and library details the **compiler** accepts. Some compilers have a thing named `random()`, but `random()` is not part of the C or C++ standard libraries.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: updated the code into the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`random()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) function from `stdlib.h` is actually a POSIX function, not a C one. So it is only guaranteed to be available in POSIX systems, such as Linux.

If you want to be portable to other C environments, use [`rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand).

Or if you use `C++`, as your tag suggest, and a not too old compiler, you can use the functions from [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Answer (score 3):

random() and srandom() are part of POSIX and not available on Windows.
 rand() and srand() are part of the standard library and will be provided by any standard conforming implementation of C++.

You can use `<random>`, which was implemented in C++11.